# Write a program that prompts for two file names and exchanges the contents of the two files

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am getting some errors that i cant figure out how to fix with the below program, here is the instructions for it.
"Write a program that prompts for two file names and exchanges the contents of the two files. Your program should be sufficiently robust that if a file doesn't exist, the program will re-prompt."

below is the error i get when i am trying to run it. I also evidently still need to make it re-prompt for the user if the files cant is found. I tried a few things to get it to work but was unable to get it to work properly for that as well.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\istal\Desktop\6.2.py", line 30, in <module>
    dataobject.transfer(firstfilename,secondfilename)
  File "C:\Users\istal\Desktop\6.2.py", line 5, in transfer
    with open(firstfilename,'r')as filedata:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/istal/Desktop/python/testone.tx'
```

here is the code itself

```
class DataTransferinFiles():
def transfer(self,firstfilename,secondfilename):
    print("your first file is=",firstfilename);
    print("your second file is =", secondfilename)
    with open(firstfilename,'r')as filedata:
        firstfiledata= filedata.readlines()
        print()
        print("1st file reading complete")
        print()
    with open(secondfilename, 'r')as filedata:
        secondfiledata=filedata.readlines()
        print("2st file reading complete")

    for eachline in firstfiledata:
       filesecond = open(secondfilename,'a')
       filesecond.write("/n"+eachline+ "/n")
       print ("1st file transfered in to second file")

    for eachline in secondfiledata:
        filefirst = open(firstfilename)
        filefirst.write("\n"+eachline+ "\n")
        print ("second file transfered in to first file")

dataobject = DataTransferinFiles()

firstfilename = input("enter first file name for transfer")
secondfilename = input("enter second file name for transfer")


dataobject.transfer(firstfilename,secondfilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an typo, of the indentation.

The line:

```
        dataobject = DataTransferinFiles()
```

Should be just:

```
    dataobject = DataTransferinFiles()
```

So the full code:

```
class DataTransferinFiles():
    def transfer(self,firstfilename,secondfilename):
        print("your first file is=",firstfilename);
        print("your second file is =", secondfilename)
        with open(firstfilename,'r')as filedata:
            firstfiledata= filedata.readlines()
            print()
            print("1st file reading complete")
            print()
        with open(secondfilename, 'r')as filedata:
            secondfiledata=filedata.readlines()
            print("2st file reading complete")

        for eachline in firstfiledata:
           filesecond = open(secondfilename,'a')
           filesecond.write("/n"+eachline+ "/n")
           print ("1st file transfered in to second file")

        for eachline in secondfiledata:
            filefirst = open(firstfilename)
            filefirst.write("\n"+eachline+ "\n")
            print ("second file transfered in to first file")

dataobject = DataTransferinFiles()

firstfilename = input("enter first file name for transfer")
secondfilename = input("enter second file name for transfer")


dataobject.transfer(firstfilename,secondfilename)
```

Comment: Thank you, but i did already figure that out, i am still getting a error

      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\istal\Desktop\6.2.py", line 30, in <module>
    dataobject.transfer(firstfilename,secondfilename)
  File "C:\Users\istal\Desktop\6.2.py", line 5, in transfer
    with open(firstfilename,'r')as filedata:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ' C:\\Users\\istal\\Desktop\\python\\testone.txt'

Comment: @Jacob amm.. that should give the same error... can please retry.

Comment: @Jacob What you inputted in the input statement?

Comment: enter first file name for transfer C:\Users\istal\Desktop\python\testtwo.txt

enter second file name for transfer  C:\Users\istal\Desktop\python\testone.txt

Comment: @Jacob In your input it should be `/` not `\`.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean there

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I edited the original post to show it.

Comment: @Jacob Sorry for delay of reply time, you're sure the file-path exists...

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a couple of issues.

1. In the `for eachline in...` blocks you are trying to reopen files that you have not closed. Add a `with` when you open them to write, the same way that you used the `with` context manager for the first. Otherwise you're trying to open the file every time you write a line.
2. The `for eachline in secondfiledata` does not append like the first does -- so if you were successfully closing the file, you'd just keep overwriting until the final line.
3. You're overcomplicating this by using `readlines()` instad of `read()`.
4. This assumes that you are reading and writing text in the files. What if it's a binary file?

I recommend perusing https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: I changed it to read instead of readlines. for your first suggestions where would i add in the with to the program. I have tried it where it seems to me like it would go with no luck.
I see what you mean with the second suggestion how would you suggest i fix the error?

Comment: In the same way that you use `with open(firstfilename,'r') as filedata:` (a context manager) around `firstfiledata= filedata.read()`, you can later use `with open(filefirst,'w')` around the corresponding write statement(s).

Comment: I am not sure how to mark things as code in comments,
I added "with open(filesecond,'w'): "
before each for the statement as I believe that what you meant and i am still getting a error